# How to add a div tag at the same place after it is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the headers befor i expor the data into excel, hide doesnt work because the data is still there, so i was using remove. but once removed, after the exporting to excel is completed i wanted to undo the removed headers for display.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
                alert("");
                $head=$('tr.header');
                $div=$('#dvData')
                $div.remove('tr.header');
                alert();
                window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +encodeURIComponent($div.html()));
                e.preventDefault();

            });
        </script>
```

i was trying to save the div object in a variable process on that variable div and send it, bt the div sent shows no changes!!

Comment: Use `display:none` instead.

Comment: display none will just hide it, but the data still goes to the excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a clone, remove whatever you want, and get the HTML

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var div   = $('#dvData'),
        clone = div.clone();

    clone.find('tr.header').remove();

    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( clone.html() ));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know the concept of clone, thanks to you learned new thing.

Comment: can u help me, how can i give the save as future to save it in a particular folder. plz help

Comment: You can't, the user decides if and where to save

Answer (score 1):

append saved variable to parent of the deleted div.

Answer (score 0):

Add it before the target element...remove it post that...

```
$(function() {

    $('#add').click(function(){
        var div = $('div.toRemove');
        var newDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('added').html('hello world');
        //newDiv.prependTo(div);
        div.before(newDiv);
        this.disabled = true;
        div.remove();        
    });

    $('#reset').click(function(){
       $('div').remove();
        $(document.body).append($('<div/>').addClass('toRemove').html('toremove'));
        $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/wnu9pv9y/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You must use `var` for each variable such as `$head` and `$div`

You can use clone to achieve the desired result.

```
            $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
                var $clonedDiv = $('#dvData').clone(true);
                $clonedDiv.find("tr.header");
                window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +encodeURIComponent($clonedDiv.html()));
                e.preventDefault();

            });
        </script>
```

use `clone(true)` to retain the events

Answer (score 0):

As per understanding you first want to remove the header before export and then want to add to the table as it is. if i am properly understanding your requirement try the following

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
            alert("");
            $div = $('#dvData')
            $divToRemain = $div.find('#TableId thead')
            $div.find('#TableId thead').remove();
            window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($div.html()));
            $divToRemain.appendTo('#tblHoliday');
            e.preventDefault();

        });
```

Here i save the removed header in the variable and after export i appended it to the table.

Hope this will help.

Comment: its better to clone the element and then work on it, but thanks for the anwer